# Modifying JSON file using data from CSV in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I'm trying to modify some specific values in a .json file based on two columns in a .csv file. If the current value in the .json file is identical to the one in the left column, I want to change it to the one in the right column.

This is my first time with PowerShell though, so I'm struggling to figure out how to go about doing this. I feel like my solution is not only wrong, but is using a double for loop when it might not need to. Here's what I have so far.

```
$jsonData = Get-Content -Path $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json
$csvData = Get-Content -Path $csvFile | Select-Object -Skip 1 # Skipping the header

foreach ($jsonItem in $jsonData.'Placeable List') {
    foreach ($csvRow in $csvData) {
        $splitRow = $csvRow -split ","
        $lCol = $splitRow[0]
        $rCol = $splitRow[1]

        $currentItem = $jsonItem.'value'.'Appearance'.'value'
        if ($currentItem -eq $lCol) {
            $currentItem -eq $rCol
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.

```
$csvData  = Get-Content -Path $csvFile | Select-Object -Skip 1 # Skipping the header
$jsonData = Get-Content -Path $jsonFile -raw | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($csvRow in $csvData) {
    $splitRow = $csvRow -split ","
    $lCol = $splitRow[0]
    $rCol = $splitRow[1]

    foreach($item in $jsonData.'Placeable List'.value) {
        $item.Appearance | % {
            if ($_.value -eq $lCol) {
                $_.value = $rCol
            }
        }
    }
}

$jsonData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32 | Set-Content $jsonFile
```